# How to fetch the id from Caraousel and display the information about specific image?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<div id='myCarousel' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel' data-
interval='false'>
  <div class='carousel-inner'>
    <div class='item active' id='111'>
      <img  src='111.jpg' alt='Image 1'/>
    </div>
    <div class='item' id='112'>
      <img  src='112.jpg' alt='Image 2'/>
    </div>
    <div class='item' id='113'>
      <img  src='113.jpg' alt='Image 3'/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class='left carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' data-slide='prev'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span>
    <span class='sr-only'>Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class='right carousel-control' href='#myCarousel' data-slide='next' 
  onclick='getid()'>
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span>
    <span class='sr-only'>Next</span>

  </a>
</div>

javascript : 
$('.glyphicon-chevron-left, .glyphicon-chevron-right').on('click', function 
() {
   var id = $('.carousel-inner').find('item.active').data('id');
   alert(id);

$('#myCarousel').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
   console.log('after');
});
```

Above is my bootstrap carousel I want to fetch the item active carousel id and display the details about current image below the carousel without postback and also there will be a button which onclick will postback data back to database. 
Below carousel data will change as slide change.I have search and tried lot of option but not getting result. Above javascript code I tried to fetch the id but its not working. Can anyone please guide on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   console.log(slide.$slides.get(index).attr('id'))
```

Comment: "slide is not defined" maybe cuz it is "slid"?

Comment: "slid is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.glyphicon-chevron-left, .glyphicon-chevron-right').on('click', function 
() {
    var id = $('.carousel-inner').find('item:active').attr('id');
    alert(id);

    $('#myCarousel').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
      console.log('after');
    }
});
```

You can get the value of any attribute from an HTML DOM element through `attr` method.

Comment: @GauravBhagwatkar Try `$('.carousel-inner').hasClass('item.active').attr('id');`

Comment: What error are you getting? Or what value are you receiving in the alert/console? Are you able to call the function onClick on the given carousel? @GauravBhagwatkar

Comment: The above script was not triggering, I tried doing modifications in that but than too no result finally i added anchor tag in carousel and fetched id on OnClick script and it solved my problem. Anyways thank you so much for suppot.